# importing and loading array of textures and adding magfilter to each texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, hook, react-three-fiber

I have a group of images that I want to use as textures in my game in react-three-fiber so I thought rather than loading them one by one and writing repeating code using textureloader.load() then adding magfilter to all of them one by one, I would use foreach method to iterate over them, load them and add magfilter to each of them simultaneously

```
import { NearestFilter, TextureLoader, RepeatWrapping } from 'three'
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react';

export const useTexture = () => {
    const [textures, setTextures] = useState({});
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const textureNames = ['dirt','grass']; // Replace with your texture names
      const textureLoader = new TextureLoader();
  
      const loadedTextures = {};
      textureNames.forEach((name) => {
        const texture = textureLoader.load(`images/${name}.jpg`);
       // texture.magFilter = NearestFilter;
        loadedTextures[name] = texture;
      });
  
      setTextures(loadedTextures);
    }, []);
  
    return textures;
  };
```

here I wanted to make a custom hook that returns an object that contains the loaded modified textures and I used the hook in this way

```
import {usePlane} from "@react-three/cannon"
import {useTexture} from "../images/textures"
import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber"
export const Ground = ()=>{

    const [ref] = usePlane(()=>({
        position:[0,0,0],rotation:[0,0,0]
    }))

      const textures = useTexture();
 
      const active_texture = textures["grass"]
    return(
        <mesh ref={ref}>
            <planeGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100,100]}/>
            <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" map={active_texture}/>
        </mesh>
    )
}
```

the problem is there is no errors but the texture is not appearing, (the plane just appears grey ) please help me and thank you in advance

it worked thank you very much I just corrected the images path

I'm facing another problem textures object is undefined for a short period of time then it's defined if I use use props.texture like this

```
   import {usePlane} from "@react-three/cannon"
   import {useTexture} from "../images/textures"
   import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber"
   export const Ground = (props)=>{
   
       const [ref] = usePlane(()=>({
           position:[0,0,0],rotation:[0,0,0]
       }))
   
         const textures = useTexture();
    
         const active_texture = textures[props.texture]
       return(
           <mesh ref={ref}>
               <planeGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100,100]}/>
               <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" map={active_texture}/>
           </mesh>
       )
   }
```

But if I destructure the props it will be undefined then defined and the texture will not be loaded like this

```
       import {usePlane} from "@react-three/cannon"
        import {useTexture} from "../images/textures"
        import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber"
        export const Ground = ({texture})=>{
    
        const [ref] = usePlane(()=>({
            position:[0,0,0],rotation:[0,0,0]
        }))
    
          const textures = useTexture();
     
          const active_texture = textures[{texture}]
        return(
            <mesh ref={ref}>
                <planeGeometry attach="geometry" args={[100,100]}/>
                <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" map={active_texture}/>
            </mesh>
        )
    }
```